Cloudflare is causing i.sstatic.net images to return 429s
After loading a chat transcript with a large number of images, requests to i.sstatic.net have started returning 429s and a Cloudflare CAPTCHA check, which... seems to defeat the point of a dedicated image hosting service? See also Cloudflare protection is triggering on Stack Overflow authentication API routes.

I have the same on the league page for the user profile images: https://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/week/stackoverflow/2024-05-12?sort=reputationchange&page=6 here is what my dev console says: https://i.sstatic.net/cWQ3IU2g.png

No repro, most likely there were thousands of requests from the same IP (maybe shared?) hence it was considered as attack and blocked.

Are they serving all the images directly from their servers‽ I'd have thought they'd at least be using the CDN.

The 429s have stopped, but the fact that this happened at all doesn't seem right. Generally, when a browser fetches an image, it doesn't expect a bunch of HTML back...

Kind of repro'd when I opened SOfT a few days ago, my avatar couldn't not be loaded, then opening the image in a new tab showing a CAPTCHA check, which I manually did, but the image still not loaded until few hours later.

I would think the rationale for the "bunch of HTML back" is the same as in https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/399874/ : (1) The response is the same for all content; the HTML message is there, as a courtesy, to be served on regular HTML pages. (2) It can be safely ignored when the browser does not expect HTML: what really matters is only the status code.
